# Flask app serve as two different apps

Tags: python, rest, flask

I had worked with the Flask application which functions as an admin panel and an API. My admin panel includes login page and bunch of admin stuff in it. So I don't want to expose it to the internet.Admin panel should be only accessible from the intranet however my API should be accessible from the internet.

I have two machines.One is a local machine and other one will be hosted at the AWS. The problem is that the code will be same in the  two machines however one will serve as an API and other will serve as an Admin panel.
My supervisor told me that I can use "Flask blueprints" to achieve what I am trying to do but I want to be sure before starting to implement.

Can Flask blueprints solve this problem or are there any other options?

(One thing comes to mind is to separate the API from the admin panel into two different Flask apps. Which is easy to do and solves everything. However I am unable to do that right now. )

[Image of what I am trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Axy1o.png)

Comment: Yes, use bĺueprints and add them to your app(s) as desired.

Comment: Yes, I Agree with Klaus

Answer (score 0):

You can use before_app_request on your blueprint and check if your client ip starts with 192.168 or 10.0 or 172.16

```
from flask import abort

@blueprint_1.before_request
def check_network():
    if not request.remote_addr.startswith("192.168") or ...:
            abort(404)
```

Edit : According to Blueprint documentation before_app_request  Such a function is executed before each request, even if outside of a blueprint.
use before_request instead (it will be executed before request on blueprint_1 Blueprint ...  i edited my code ...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I think attacker can still forge his/her IP to make requests to my admin panel although that's very unlikely. So I decided to use a code something like this:                                                           `if APP.config['APP_TYPE'] == 'panel'                    APP.register_blueprint(panel)                                                                         else :                                                                              APP.register_blueprint(api)`

Comment: if you have 2 physical servers and one code with different configuration then your code is right , but i mine is for using 1 server and having the result you want .